# C# Как с помощью пользовательского ввода вывести значение из листа

Tags: c#, строки, list, int

Ранее был создан список

`List<string> people = new List<string>() { "Tom", "Bob", "Sam" };`

Как при помощи команды

`int Н = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` или `string Н = Console.ReadLine();` или любой схожей с этими, вывести значения из списка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

эээ...
Ну если я правильно понял, то просто

```cs
int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(people[index]);
```